# error starting terminal in ubuntu 14.04.3 [MOVED]

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am unfamiliar with below error and how to fix it, it happens when I start the terminal in ubuntu 14.04.3.  I do not send any command only press crtl+alt+T.  It seems to indicate that something is missing from `PATH` but I'm not really sure what. Thank you :).

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
* /bin/lesspipe
* /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not    included   in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the     PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
cmccabe@HP-Z640-Workstation:~$
```

Comment: Try on superuser.com, so is about programming

Comment: I will move it... thank you